# Adding two infinite shapes to get itself?

Tags: geometry, infinity

This is at first a ridiculous question but on the other hand I'm not sure how to prove it.

Take a solid 2D shape, $A$, and duplicate it to give $A'$. The shape $A$ together with the $A'$ make a new region called $B$.

Can we take the shape $A$ and using only translation and rotation make it fill exactly the region $B$ ? (That is to say it now covers the original position of $A$ and it's copy $A'$)

Obviously if $A$ is a shape of finite extent and area this would be impossible because we are asking a shape to cover twice it's own area. But it is not so clear to me that this would be impossible if $A$ were an infinite shape, perhaps some sort of infinite wedge whose thickness follows an exponential.

Another way of saying the same thing is can we split a shape $B$ into two parts such that they both are translated, rotated copies of the original shape $B$?

If not, how can we provide a proof? (By the way without using such obscure things as the Banach–Tarski paradox. ).

I can see how this might be done with a fractal (such as Sierpiński triangle) but I am thinking about solid shapes of fractal dimension 2.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by 'duplicate $A$ to give $A'$ '? I'm imagining that $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, in which case where are you placing the copy $A'$ relative to $A$?

Comment: @AlbertWood Anywhere you please such that the two copies are not overlapping. e.g. if A was a disc then you would have two discs.

Comment: The shape A cannot have a non-zero finite area, since B has twice the area of A. So its area must either be zero or infinite.

Comment: @Jaap Yes, it says infinite in the question.  But the question is, is there such an infinite shape?

Comment: I don't think there is an infinite area solution. There is an isometry that maps B to A, and another that maps B to A'. Call those isometries $r$ and $s$. So they map B to identical disjoint copies of itself. You can repeat that, so $rr$, $rs$, $sr$, and $ss$ will map B to 4 identical disjoint copies of itself. Repeating this $n$ times, the isometries $\{r,s\}^n$ map B to $2^n$ disjoint copies of itself. If some finite region of B has non-zero area, the area gets multiplied by $2^n$, but I think the sequence of n isometries can only map this to within a region that grows quadratically with n.